# Excel C# AddIn returns error when trying to get the value inside the cell?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins

I'm trying to make an C# Excel addin in order to automate the calculus of some cells value.The error I get is "Cannot convert null to int becouse it is not a non nullable value type".From what I understand this line of code gets a null from Excel:

```
int cellValue = sheet.Cells[1, 12].Value2;
```

There are values in Excel,(so the Excel is not empty) which are set to number in Options.This is the whole code:

```
if (((RibbonCheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                app.Workbooks.Add();
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = app.ActiveSheet;
                int cellValue = sheet.Cells[1, 12].Value2;
                for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= sheet.Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                        while (sheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] != null)
                        {
                            sheet.Cells[i + 1, 8].Value2 = sheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] * cellValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Exceptie:" + ex);

            }
```

Comment: *There are values in Excel* You are not opening any existing excel. You are apparently creating a new workbook so how exactly are there going to be values in any given cell?

Comment: I add values in the new created Excel and then run the AddIn.

Comment: How did you come to understand that line is the error? If you step through with the debugger and inspect values you should be able to find the problem by cross referencing with the spreadsheet

Comment: In the posted code you are not using any pre-existing excel sheet. You are newing up a completely new one and accesing that one. The problem here seems to be that you erroneously think you are accessing a specific excel sheet.

Comment: Are you trying to reference values in the existing workbook that the AddIn is running from? Then you need to use `Excel.Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet` Otherwise when you use WorkBooks.Add, the new workbook created by the Add method has its Sheet1(blank) as the active sheet for the application. And don't create a new Application either

Comment: I tried MacroMarc solution and i received the folowing error :
'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. 
I tried to cast to Worksheet and I received the folowing error:
'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetImpl' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'.'